# Evaluating three complex integrals with varying radius

Tags: complex-analysis

I will use the principle that

> If $p$, $q$ are analytic functions, $q(a) = 0$, and $q'(a) \neq 0$ then the residue of $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ at $a$ is $\frac{p(a)}{q'(a)}$.

$\begin{align} \int_{|z|=3} \frac{\cos{z}}{(z-2)(z-4)} dz &= 2 \pi i \left(\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cos{z}}{(z-2)(z-4)}, 2\right)\right)&\text{(because |z|=3 includes 2 but not 3)} \\
&= 2\pi i \left(\frac{\cos{2}}{2(2) - 6}\right) \\
&= \pi i \cos{(2)}\end{align} $

$\begin{align} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{\cos{z}}{(z-2)(z-4)} dz &= 0 &\text{(because |z|=1 includes no points)}\\ \end{align} $

$\begin{align} \int_{|z|=5} \frac{\cos{z}}{(z-2)(z-4)} dz &= 2 \pi i \left(\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cos{z}}{(z-2)(z-4)}, 2\right) + \text{Res}\left(\frac{\cos{z}}{(z-2)(z-4)}, 4\right)\right)&\text{(because |z|=5 includes both)}\\
&= 2\pi i\left(\frac{\cos{2}}{2(2) - 6} + \frac{\cos{4}}{2(4) - 6}\right) \\
&= 2\pi i\left(\frac{\cos{2}}{-2} + \frac{\cos{4}}{2}\right) \\
&= \pi i (\cos{4} - \cos{2})\end{align} $

Comment: That's peculiar. In the first integral the contribution from the pole at $2$ is $\pi i\cos 2$ but in the third it has become $-\pi i\cos 2$.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown Double-checking is extremely non-trivial, because just going through the problem a second time usually results in you repeating the same error. So thank you.